# Add a class to table by JavaScript with conditions

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone tell me how I can add the CSS class "bestvalue" to our table (which is dynamically injected into page so don't have access to html) for all table rows with a quantity of 300 or more listed? In our example below, that would be the last 2 rows.

```
<table class="lb-vd-table">
  <thead class="lb-vd-table-head">
    <tr class="vd-table-head-row">
      <th class="lb-vd-table-head-text">QUANTITY</th>
      <th class="lb-vd-table-head-text">PRICE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="lb-vd-table-body">
    <tr class="lb-vd-table-body-row">
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text">100</td>
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text"><span class="money">$4.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lb-vd-table-body-row">
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text">200</td>
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text"><span class="money">$3.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lb-vd-table-body-row">
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text">300</td>
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text"><span class="money">$2.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lb-vd-table-body-row">
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text">400</td>
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text"><span class="money">$1.00</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Would adding it with JS be the best way?

Comment: `Would adding it with JS be the best way?` it's the only way in a browser - but if you can add it where the table is generated (server side?) then that would also work

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some relatively simple JavaScript. This code loops through all the elements with the `lb-vd-table-body-row` class. For each row it finds the first `lb-vd-table-body-text`. Then it parses the text inside the element as an integer. Finally, if the quantity is at least 300 it adds the `bestvalue` class to the row.

Note that the JavaScript is inside a `type="module"` script. this will make sure that the script runs after the table is already loaded. if you cannot do this you may need to add an event listener for the `load` event.

```html
<script type="module">
  for (let row of document.querySelectorAll(".lb-vd-table-body-row")) {
    const quantityElement = row.querySelector(".lb-vd-table-body-text:nth-child(1)");
    const quantity = parseInt(quantityElement.innerText);
    if (quantity >= 300) {
      row.classList.add("bestvalue");
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .bestvalue {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<table class="lb-vd-table">
  <thead class="lb-vd-table-head">
    <tr class="vd-table-head-row">
      <th class="lb-vd-table-head-text">QUANTITY</th>
      <th class="lb-vd-table-head-text">PRICE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="lb-vd-table-body">
    <tr class="lb-vd-table-body-row">
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text">100</td>
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text"><span class="money">$4.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lb-vd-table-body-row">
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text">200</td>
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text"><span class="money">$3.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lb-vd-table-body-row">
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text">300</td>
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text"><span class="money">$2.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lb-vd-table-body-row">
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text">400</td>
      <td class="lb-vd-table-body-text"><span class="money">$1.00</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Nate, appreciate it!!

Comment: Could I also use DEFER instead of type="module" to load the script?

Comment: Yes defer would also work. I usually prefer module because of how it scopes variables but in this case it doesn't matter.